# Trouble with writing to existing JSON file in android

Tags: android, json

I have an existing .json file in my assets folder. I can read successfully using Input steam but when I want to write to this file I'm having trouble finding it correctly. Here's how I have it now

```
 try (FileWriter file = 
   new FileWriter(getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
       "/app/src/main/assets/inventory.json")) {

     file.write(jsonObj.toString());
 }
```

Here's the error I'm getting

```
01-09 14:43:51.178 21391-21391/edu.wit.senderp.inventorytrack W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: edu.wit.senderp.inventorytrack/app/src/main/assets/inventory.json (No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Files in assets folder are read-only. And you can only access assets files via [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourceTypes

Comment: So if I need to add data to an existing JSON file what do you suggest?

Comment: You need to copy the file to a reabable and writeable location in your device.

Comment: Where is a r/w location? I'm using an emulator

Comment: ^ and how do I access that new file to 1. Read from it 2. Write to it